# Saving `editText` visibility

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have couple of `editTexts` that are set to visible on a `button` click and I also have another`button` that will set the `editText` to invisible. When I save the visibility code by itself the code works fine but when I add in the code to save the `editText` to invisibe, I'm running into problems. What am I doing wrong?

```
    public void EditTextVisible() {
    visibility++;
    if(e1.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        e1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else if(e2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
        e2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
public void invisible(){
    invisible++;
    if(e2.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        e2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else if(e1.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        e1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
@Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();

    editor.putInt(key1, visibility);//This code is working by itself.

    editor.putInt(key2, invisible); //When I add this code to save the editText to invisible nothing is being saved on exit.

    editor.commit();

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        int val = prefs.getInt(key1, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
            EditTextVisible();

        prefs.getInt(key2, 0);
        int inv = prefs.getInt(key2, 1);
        for (int a = 0; a < inv; a++)
              invisible();

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any kind of use of 'visibility++' and 'invisible', And tell us what problem you are facing clearly.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Which problem? @Gunaseelan

Comment: The issue is when i try to save the number of times the user set the editText to invisible, the code is not working. For example, user clicks the button to set the editText to visible, that is saved by EditTextvisible code in onResume that code is working but when i try to save the number of times the user set the edittext to invisible, it's not being saved by the invisibe(); code i added in onResume. sorry if there's any confusion @Gunaseelan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your `onResume()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        int val = prefs.getInt(key1, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < val; i++)
            EditTextVisible();


        int inv = prefs.getInt(key2, 0);
        for (int a = 0; a < inv; a++)
              invisible();

    }
```

Please check this code.

Comment: I know I'm making a mistake in `onResume` trying to recall the number of time the editText view has been set to invisible but i cant figure out what it is.

Comment: How much time your loop is running?

Comment: The loop is running 3 times

Comment: can you try without loop, then the issue would be more clear.

Comment: I actually figured out what I was doing wrong. I was making a mistake in my loop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is not clear .But here is something is wrong

```
int inv = prefs.getInt(key 2, 1);
```

it should be

```
int inv = prefs.getInt(key2, 1);
```